# Word embedding, data formatting unsure of how to bring together

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to go through a tutorial and re-apply it to another problem for practice. the original tutorial is here, https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word_embeddings .

I am using this dataset instead though and optimizing for profitable at the end,

```
id - product - url - html_snippet - html_blob - profitable
1 - toygun - "https://toyguns.com" - "a place for toy guns" - "<!DOCTYPE html><ht.." - 1
1 - umbrella - "https://umbrellas.com" - "a place for umbrellas" - "<!DOCTYPE ...." - 0
```

Example of getting data is like this,

```
url = 'https://moodmap.app'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
s = soup.select('html')[0].text.strip('jQuery1720724027235122559_1542743885014(').strip(')')
s = s.replace('null','"placeholder"')

print(soup)
```

Now when i try and put this data into this format, it is coming up with a few errors and I'm confused if it's possible to put it in the same format as in this example?

```
...
batch_size = 1024
seed = 123
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'aclImdb/train', batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.2, 
    subset='training', seed=seed)
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'aclImdb/train', batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.2, 
    subset='validation', seed=seed)
..
```

With this from directory section, can i parse in a dataframe with these values above?

```
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

With this section, the 1000 word vocbulary, is this right for the content i'm putting in?

```
# Embed a 1,000 word vocabulary into 5 dimensions.
embedding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(1000, 5)

result = embedding_layer(tf.constant([1,2,3]))
result.numpy()

result = embedding_layer(tf.constant([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]))
result.shape

# Create a custom standardization function to strip HTML break tags '<br />'.
def custom_standardization(input_data):
  lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_data)
  stripped_html = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, '<br />', ' ')
  return tf.strings.regex_replace(stripped_html,
                                  '[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '')

# Vocabulary size and number of words in a sequence.
vocab_size = 10000
sequence_length = 100

# Use the text vectorization layer to normalize, split, and map strings to 
# integers. Note that the layer uses the custom standardization defined above. 
# Set maximum_sequence length as all samples are not of the same length.
vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
    standardize=custom_standardization,
    max_tokens=vocab_size,
    output_mode='int',
    output_sequence_length=sequence_length)
```

I think the rest should work.

Would love some help here - perhaps I am approaching this incredibly incorrectly, but seems like a similar workflow?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error? Do you have data from your own custom dataset in the folders mentioned in the the `text_dataset_from_directory` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but assuming you have some sort of text data you want to feed into a neural network with an embedding layer for classification purposes, I would approach it like this:

First, as you are experimenting, I would work with the raw data instead of using **tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory**, just to avoid any confusion about the nature and structure of your data. It would also allow you to not have a static Train Test split, which in my experience is needed for more stable solutions.

This means that I would load your entire dataset, preprocess it, and then split it up into Test, Training, and Validation datasets. I prefer doing this in the explorative phase, as I believe it makes understanding your data easier. Also i will be using some packages that I recommend you learn to use if you do not already use them (pandas, numpy, sklearn) So something like this (assuming your data is in a CSV file):

```
# ----- Import needed packages -----
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report
from collections import Counter

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

# ----- Load data -----
file_path = "/PATH/TO/DATA/data.csv"
df = pd.read_pickle(file_path)

# ----- Get labels -----
y = np.int32(df.NAME_OF_LABEL_COLUMN.astype('category').cat.codes.to_numpy())

# ----- Get number of classes -----
num_classes = np.unique(y).shape[0]

# ----- Remove HTML tags from your text -----
def custom_standardization(text):
    #rewrite your function to apply on each text in your data
    pass

df['Cleaned_Text'] = df.NAME_OF_TEXT_COLUMN.apply(custom_standardization)

# ----- Prepare text for embedding -----
# Define these values so they fit your project
max_features = 10000
output_dim = 16

# ----- Get top 10000 most occuring words in list-----
results = Counter()
df['Cleaned_Text'].str.split().apply(results.update)
vocabulary = [key[0] for key in results.most_common(max_features)]

# ----- Create tokenizer based on your top 10000 words -----
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_features)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(vocabulary)

# ----- Convert words to ints and pad -----
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['Cleaned_Text'].values)
X = pad_sequences(X)

max_input_lenght = X.shape[1]

# ----- Split into Train, Test, Validation sets -----
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

Then once preprocessing is done, we can construct and train the model

```
# ----- Define model -----
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=max_features, output_dim=output_dim, input_length=max_input_lenght))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

# ----- Compile model -----
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4), metrics=["accuracy"])

# ----- Train model -----
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=8,epochs=20, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))

# ----- Evaluate model -----
probabilities = model.predict(X_test)
pred = np.argmax(probabilities, axis=1)

print(" ")
print("Results")

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, pred)

print('Accuracy: {:.4f}'.format(accuracy))
print(" ")
print(classification_report(y_test, pred))
```

This code could be improved on, but I think it will be easier for you to test whatever you are trying to test, as it provides more transparency in each step. And you will of course need to modify it to suit your specific case.

If you are keen on using the Tensorflow example you based your work on, I would suggest that you take a look at the data format in your own case and in the tutorial case, as that is likely where the issue is.

Comment: If the size of the dataset is very large, is there a way to carry this process out in batches without the use of **tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory**? And feed it into the model in batches?